# How to fix media test error after installing elementary os?

Tags: system-installation

I am new to elementary os.I was trying to dual boot elementary os and windows 10. So, my problem is that I installed elementary os by following the article from foss website. After I finished installing at the last step where I had to remove the pendrive I messed up. I removed pendrive before restarting the laptop. Now I can't even boot in to Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Put the usb stick once again, power on machine hold F12, choose the usb stick to boot and try to install the Elementary OS again. You can select the existing partition with Elementary OS as a target partition.